# How to prevent devices lower than Lollipop from installing my app?

Tags: android

How to prevent devices lower than Lollipop from installing my app from Google play?
Is there a solution from google play developer console or from the config file ?

Comment: downvote as this is a basic thing for Android developers. Use the **AndroidManifest.xml** file to set *minSdkVersion* to 21

Answer (score 3):

You can specify that in your app's manifest file with `<uses-sdk />`. It has a `android:minSdkVersion` attribute that can be used to set a minimum. The [Lollipop API level is 21](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html). So if you want Lollipop and above, use:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
```

You probably already have a `<uses-sdk />` node in your manifest. You can only have one, so you'd need to update your existing node.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in your `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
}
```